# start gdalbuildvrt from c++ plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, c++

I want to create a vrt from my plugin via gdal-tool. From OSGEO4W-Shell the command works. In my code i tried this:

```
QString program = "gdalbuildvrt";
                    QStringList arguments;
                    arguments.append("C:\\Temp\\output.vrt");
                    arguments.append("P:\\Daten\\Rasterdatenkatalog\\Raster1\\kat_1\\teil1\\4331ein.tif");
                    arguments.append("P:\\Daten\\Rasterdatenkatalog\\Raster1\\kat_1\\teil1\\4332ein.tif");
                    arguments.append("P:\\Daten\\Rasterdatenkatalog\\Raster1\\kat_1\\teil1\\4333ein.tif");

                    QProcess p;
                    p.start(program, arguments);
                    if (p.waitForStarted())
                    {
                        p.waitForFinished();
                        qDebug() << p.readAllStandardOutput();
                    }
                    else
                        qDebug() << "Failed to start";
```

I get no errormessage but the file will not be created. Do I need the full path to gdalbuildvrt? I thought in qgis the path is even set.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Echo your path and check whether gdal is there?

Comment: I gave the program the full path to gdalbuildvrt but it doesn't helped.